# Getting an InterfaceError for SQLAlchemy when typing messages in Flask-SocketIO

Tags: javascript, python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-socketio

'''
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: 'INSERT INTO history (sender_id, recipient_id, message, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (None, None, {'message': 'Hei', 'username': 'ram2'}, '2020-02-12 15:43:53.386001')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
'''

Comment: You are trying to write a dictionary as an attribute in one of your models.

Comment: So what do I have to do?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you would know what to do. You need to set the attributes of your models to their correct types. You cannot write a dictionary in an attribute that is defined as a simple type.